# How can I sort serializer data on serializer MethodField while using ListViewSet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a class say GetStudentDetails and I am using a serializer having serializer MethodField say postal_address and I want my result to be sorted on based of this field

I have tried adding ordering = ('postal_address',) and since it is not a model field, I encounter error.

```py
class GetStudentDetails(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    model = Student
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentCreateSerializer
    filter_backends = 
    (filters.OrderingFilter,filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)

class StudentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    postal_address = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_postal_address(self, obj):
        return Address.objects.get(name=obj.name).address

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ('name','city','state',postal_address')

class Address(models.Model):
    name=models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=45)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return name
```

actual result:

```
[{"name":test",
"city":"abc",
"state":"def",
"postal_address":"abcdef"
},
{
"name":"test2",
"city":"aa",
"state":"bb",
"postal_address":"aabb"
}]
```

expected result:

```
[{
"name":"test2",
"city":"aa",
"state":"bb",
"postal_address":"aabb"
},
{"name":test",
"city":"abc",
"state":"def",
"postal_address":"abcdef"
}]
```

Comment: you want alphabetical sorting based on the method field `postal_address` which is a string of `city` + `state` attributes? I only ask because your expected result doesn't include that field, it includes a `postal_code` field instead which is not shown anywhere else...

Comment: updated my question

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would try ordering by the 2 fields you are combining:

```
ordering = ('city', 'state')
```

UPDATE:

according to your changed criteria, try:

```
ordering = ('address_set__address', )
```

although according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217948/specifying-order-by-on-related-field-in-django) there are issues with this method that the answerer addressed by hardcoding the ordering into the related model. So in your case:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('address',)
```

then in your other model/serializer:

```
ordering = ('address_set', )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it may work in this case but say if my method field is from other model, than how would I sort now (question updated)

Comment: It didn't work for me. I had to implement list method in view and there I sorted using itemgetter from operator package. But I am looking for a solution without going in this way.